# Dynamically create an array of object pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

I have a class called "poly". I want to dynamically create an array of pointers to poly objects.  The variable "totalPolynomials" holds the number of poly objects.

Here is my code to declare the array:

```
poly **polyPtr;                         
polyPtr = new poly *[totalPolynomials];
```

I successfully create poly objects, but don't know how to store their pointers in the array one after another...

Comment: I suggest to use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<poly>>` (or `std::vector<poly*>`).

Comment: I would advise against this. Do what @Jarod42 says, instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are creating them and then want to store them, you can do something like

```
poly ** polyPtr;
polyPtr = new poly* [totalPolynomials];

for(int i = 0; i<totalPolynomials; ++i)
{
    polyPtr[i] = new poly(arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually setting the pointers in the array, so a a demonstration, you would be writing something like this:

```
poly** polyPtr = new poly*[totalPolynomials];
for(int i = 0; i < totalPolynomials; ++i)
    // You may need to pass constructor arguments here.
    polyPtr[i] = new poly();
    // or polyPtr[i] = myOtherPointer; in case you just wanna share it.
```

Storing you pointers would be similar instead of allocating memory for new ones. Basically, you would need to replace the new with your pointers.

No answer can go without the warning that you should consider higher-level data and memory management than this when programming in C++ for your productivity and mental well-being.

So, I would suggest using something like this:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<poly>>
```

or

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<poly>>
```

Depending on your exact desire.

Comment: I don't think he is trying to create a 2D array, but rather a 1D array of pointers...